# How to add column in resultset in java?

Tags: java, sql, resultset

I have table employee

I retrieve the columns as  `select emp_name,emp_add from employee`

```
while(iResultSet1.next())
            {
                List expRptColWise = new ArrayList();

                for(Integer i=1;i<=iResultSet1.getMetaData().getColumnCount();i++){


                        expRptColWise.add(iResultSet1.getString(i));

                }

                expRptRowWise.add(expRptColWise);
```

With the above snippet ,I get

```
emp_name | emp_add |
A        | add1    |
B        | add2    |
```

I want to add Serial No. coloumn in resultset so that I get result as

```
emp_name | emp_add |Sr_No|
A        | add1    |1    |
B        | add2    |2    |
```

Please guide me how to add column dynamically in resultset or collection object ,Here I have used ArrayList.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: You can use `row_number()` as a column in your query and get that in the resultset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a Counter in the While Loop which you increments each time and use it in the output:

```
int j = 0;
while(iResultSet1.next())
{
   j++;
   List expRptColWise = new ArrayList();
   for(Integer i=1;i<=iResultSet1.getMetaData().getColumnCount();i++)
   {
      expRptColWise.add(iResultSet1.getString(i));
   }
   expRptColWise.add(j);
   expRptRowWise.add(expRptColWise);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

use the following query

```
 select emp_name,emp_add, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY emp_name)) AS sr_no from employee
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer DinupKandel's response, but just because we shouldn't put all our eggs in the same basket

```
int row = 0;
while(iResultSet1.next())
{
    List expRptColWise = new ArrayList();
    for(Integer i=1;i<=iResultSet1.getMetaData().getColumnCount();i++){
        expRptColWise.add(iResultSet1.getString(i));
    }
    expRptColWise.add(++row);
    expRptRowWise.add(expRptColWise);
}
```

Might work for you

Comment: Nope ... u beat me ... 10 Milliseconds :)